# Combination of perpendicular simple harmonic motions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

We solve questions for two simple harmonic motions which are said to be perpendicular but while solving their angles or phase differences is not 90° so what is the significance of perpendicular shms

Answer (score 2):

First, I am interpreting your "phase difference" as the phase difference between the x-direction and y-direction oscillation.

Think about the two limiting cases: if the phase difference is zero, then the effective motion is an oscillation in the y=x plane; if the phase difference is 90 degree, then the effective motion is a circular motion. So what do you think is the trajectory for the cases in-between, when the phase difference is between 0 and 90 degree?

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting that assigning a *single* phase difference implies the same period for both basis directions. If the periods are different you get a slightly more complicagted behavior (non-trivial lissajous figures).